# Reading file contents does not produce file contents

Tags: windows, vbscript, filesystems

I have a generic SQL file containing a boring SQL Script. Nothing unusual. However, when I try to read it using VBScript, it produces this output:

```
Microsoft (R) Windows Script Host Version 5.8
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

˜_
```

And nothing else. Here is my VBScript code that does not work:

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

WScript.Echo objFSO.OpenTextFile("PARTY_FK_CONSTRAINTS.SQL").ReadAll()
```

I have tried this in Windows 7 as well as Windows Server 2008 R2. Also worth mentioning is that I can read it just fine in C#. I don't know if something strange is happening transparently through the filesystem or what. What's going on?

Comment: I suspects the source file is not ASCII/ANSI encoded. The FSO can handle ASCII/ANSI encoding or UTF-16 (optional param to OpenTextFile() method).

Comment: @Ekkehard.Horner Thank you! Per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/314cz14s(v=vs.84).aspx) I added -2 to the OpenTextFile() call and it works. Submit your comment as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: @Ekkehard.Horner If you submit your comment as an answer, I will accept it.